# PHP imagick COMPOSITE_DSTIN result has black background

Tags: php, imagick

I try to set a text gradient from this solution here https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/gd-text-gradient/82127/9

But the background color of the final image is black, I try `$im->flattenImages` and `$img->setBackgroundColor` but it's not working.

```
$im = new Imagick();

        $draw = new ImagickDraw();
        $draw->setFontSize(90);
        $draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel("black"));
        $draw->setTextEncoding('UTF-8');
        $draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

        $metric = $im->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);

        $width = $metric['textWidth'];
        $height = $metric['textHeight'];

        /* Create and save the gradiant */
        $Imagick = new Imagick();
        $Imagick->newPseudoImage($height, $width, "gradient:#FB7F4C-#FF409C");
        /*** rotate the image ***/
        $Imagick->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(), 270);
        $Imagick->setImageFormat('png');
        $Imagick->writeImage("gradiant.png");

        /* Create and save the canvas */
        $im->newPseudoImage($width, $height, "null:");
        $im->setImageFormat('png');
        $im->writeImage("canvas.png");

        /* Add the text to the canvas ( Make the mask )*/
        $im = new Imagick("canvas.png");

// Write the text on the image
        $im->annotateImage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);
        $im->setImageBackgroundColor("transparent"); // <= Here
        /* Final image */
        $canvas = new Imagick("gradiant.png");
        $canvas->compositeImage($im, imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTIN, 0, 0, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

        $canvas->setImageFormat('png');
        $canvas->writeImage(__DIR__ . "/../../final.png");

        header('Content-Type: image/' . $im->getImageFormat());
        echo $canvas;

        unlink("canvas.png");
        unlink("gradiant.png");
```

I found after the `COMPOSITE_DSTIN` the background color goes black, I try many way but its not working

How to remove black background?

Comment: What version of PHP and Imagick library?

Comment: @bishop PHP Version 7.1.26, imagick module version  3.4.3, ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2016-06-16, Also it's not possible to change these version because I using shared host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm solved it by adding alphachannel

I try `$canvas->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_RESET);` and after that the background stay transparent

**UPDATE**

After I updated my imagick library it's stop working and search for similar issue and found this [Imagemagick compose image inverted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187807/imagemagick-compose-image-inverted)

And here the code that works well

```
$canvas->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
```